# Read stream of bits from GPIO on Pi using Python

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, bit, gpio

I need to read a stream of bits that get sent to a GPIO port on a Pi using Python.

If I were to create a loop to just append an array with what ever it reads from the GPIO port it may read an incorrect value as the speed at which it is reading is faster than the speed of the device that is sending the stream.

I want to know if there is a way to open the port for input for a set length of time and then append to an array either a 1 or a 0 depending on the GPIO state (HIGH or LOW).

Thanks

Comment: > *For Raspberry Pi, please tag with "raspberry-pi"* from [tag:pi] tag info page.

Comment: Without a defined speed or other synchronization theres hardly a way to properly read the stream.

Comment: This is not a correct way to go. You should not rely on timing. You need synchronization, which typically is achieved using dedicated interrupt pin.

Comment: Can you elaborate on the interrupt pin. Is this held open for input and capture changes in the state ?